# SQL query deleting all records older than the last one

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I'd like to create a SQL oracle request in the following contexts :

I've got a table where the user name is the primary key.
This table got hundred of records for each user name with a last modification date.

I'd like to remove all the records with a modification date being 1 month older than the most recent one, and so for each user name.

I guess I could simply use two instances of my table (one to perform the delete, and one to perform the select with the most recent record then joining the two), but I'm really not sure about this.

Is someone having any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to write a `SELECT` statement to display all of the records that should be deleted?

Comment: PL/SQL would be easy to develop and maintain.!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this according to your columns

```
DELETE username 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  created_date >= To_date(?, 'dd-MON-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
       AND created_date <= To_date(?, 'dd-MON-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: I think the Question was for each user name.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar yea It will take each user name if that condition match (WHERE clause)

Comment: No, the delete has to be based on 30 days from last available date, for each user. The last available date may not be same for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the last modification date for each user_name in the inner query (denoted by alias `i` in the query below), and delete any row for that user having last_modification_date at least 30 days before the latest one.

```
Delete from tablename o
where o.last_modification_date + 30 < (select max(i.last_modification_date) 
from tablename i
where i.user_name = o.user_name)
```

This query will only work if the data type of last_modification_date is `date`, `datetime` etc.

Comment: The issue with your query will be that if a user had a record with the last modification date the 30th, and one the 20th, it will consider only the date for the first one. I would like the query to perform the  max for each user individually (retrieve all the records for the first one, one month before the 30th, and for the second one, one month before the 20th).

Comment: This is exactly what the abov query does. It does it per userwise

Answer (score 0):

To delete all records for which there is another for the same user name and having a modification date more than one month later, use:

```
delete from my_table t1
where exists (select null
                from my_table t2
               where t2.username          = t1.username and
                     t2.modification_date > add_months(t1.modification_date,1))
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want to delete all the records, but just the ones older than one month (not the records within the current month).

Comment: Older than the most recent record for that user name?